# Sublime Text 3 stops working when I close a python Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, sublimetext3

I made a simple calculator in python in half an hour for a school demonstration. I made that using the stock python IDE. I decided to take the file home and work on it a little more but I prefer using Sublime Text 3 for it. My only problem now is that every time I close the tkinter window, ST3 stops working. I have tried reinstalling it several times and I even reinstalled python out of sheer desperation.

EDIT:
Any tkinter-window does this to ST, no matter how big or small. I'm running Python 3.5.0 right out of ST, which works fine for everything else.
For the sake of example, here's a simple tkinter window with a button in a frame:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        button = Button(frame, text="text", width=3)
        button.pack()

root=Tk()
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
root.wm_title("title")
app = App(root)
root.geometry("200x200")
root.mainloop()
```

As soon as I use the red X to close the generated window, Sublime Text crashes and doesn't recover. It's Sublime Text 3, Build 3083.

Comment: What do you mean by "the stock python IDE"? Python doesn't come with an IDE.

Comment: @BryanOakley Python does come with IDLE.

Comment: ah, ok, Yeah, I sometimes forget about IDLE. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: How is this meant to work? You haven't imported tkinter and used `tkinter.` etc. to define your widgets so it'll throw errors

Comment: How do you run it? Do you run it from the terminal or from Sublime Text? Because sublime text can't handle errors I assume... Try running it from the command line.

Comment: Please show us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): the code needs to be completely runnable on its own. Include *all* imports, classes, function definitions, etc. Also, please tell us what version of Python you're using. Use the [edit] function to add all this information to the question itself, do not post it as comments.

Comment: @MattDMo Done. Sorry for that.

Comment: @JonahFleming Running the exact same code on IDLE works fine. I can close the window no problem. But the same code in ST will cause the problem described.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes. Jesus, it's late :D

Comment: Just for funsies, try adding this line above `root.mainloop()`: `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.destroy)` and see if that doesn't fix it. (I'm kind of throwing code at the problem and seeing what sticks)

Comment: @AdamSmith It does not, unfortunately.

Comment: @FloKlar what if you change `root = Tk()` to `root = Toplevel()`?

Comment: @AdamSmith I get two windows, one blank. I can close the one with content, but when I close the blank one, same problem occurs.

Comment: @FloKlar interesting! I don't really know what's causing it. I mean Sublime uses a Python shell and a tkinter GUI to display its stuff, so there's obviously some unintended side effects there. Might be worth lodging a bug with ST

Comment: @AdamSmith I downloaded and installed ST2 now. It works fine in there. I'll do that, though.

Comment: @FloKlar A better solution is to use ST3 to develop, save your code, and run it with `python path/to/helloworld.pyw` in your console. But your mileage may vary

Comment: @FloKlar what OS are you using? I'm on OS X 10.10, running the latest dev build of Sublime (3095), and using Python/Tkinter from Macports. Your "dummy" program above runs just fine for me....

Comment: @MattDMo I'm using Windows 10 on this PC. You think it could be caused by that?

Comment: @FloKlar that's a possibility. Are you using the Python from python.org, or another distribution like Anaconda?

Comment: @MattDMo Using the official python release from python.org.